# Change URL structure of a vbulletin forum

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, vbulletin

I have a vbulletin forum installed at www.example.com/wordpress/forum. As you can guess, the directory is inside a wp install. I need this because I use the wp header and footer in my forum layout.

My question is what I can do so that my forum can be accessed at www.example.com/forum and not www.example.com/wordpress/forum.

Comment: what vbulletin version you have?

Comment: @KimTan 4.2.0 Patch Level 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the bburl in the database, but it's in the datastore table where title='options', and it's stored as a serialized array, so it's a little tricky. A less tricky way would be to edit the settings table where varname = 'bburl', then upload tools.php to your admincp directory, and use "[Options Cache]" to rebuild the datastore from the settings (you also have to upload the install directory if you've previously removed it).

Ref Link:

1. http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=317602
2. http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-4/vbulletin-4-questions-problems-and-troubleshooting/3974985-changing-domain-location-of-urls-in-database